# Manipulate a variable in a def

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alright, I'm completely changing this post- I realized that I did it wrong.

Global isn't working in def- I can print a variable, but when I try to change THE SAME VARIABLE, (Example: Test = Test + 1), it dosen't work. **I've been redirected to the 'global' fix, it dosen't work.**

**Look at this screenshot to understand my frustration**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCJIv.png

So here's what I need to solve; How do I make it so I can manipulate the 'Health' variable?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a global variable, you have to note that it's global inside the scope where you're using it:

```
Hello = 4
Hello2 = 2

def SomeLogicThing():
    global Hello
    global Hello2
    if Hello2 == 2:
        Hello = Hello + 1
```

(Also, note that `Hello + 1` doesn't do anything on its own, it's just an expression. You have to include an assignment for it to change the value, or use the `+=` operator.)

Comment: Rebind, not use.

Comment: I still get this: name 'Hello' is used prior to global declaration